# Copying and renaming images

Tags: files, file-copy

I am using Manjaro Gnu/Linux and I have a directory named `files`. Under this directory, I have around 650 sub directories, with names such as: `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3`, `dir4`, ...

Under each sub directory there are varying number of `.jpg` images (say, from 2 to 11).
Say as an example, under `dir1` subdirectory, the images are `imgaf001.jpg` and `srep0001.jpg`.

I want to write a command/script to copy all such images to a new directory names `all_images` such that the images are renamed to the names of their sub directories.

For example: For `dir1` sub directory, `imgaf001.jpg` changes to `dir1_1.jpg` and `srep0001.jpg` changes to `dir1_2.jpg` (after the underscore, the count of image comes).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run this script in the directory named `files`:

```
mkdir all_images
find -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
    c=1
    for f in "$@"; do
        pdir=${f%/*}
        pdir=${pdir##*/} #Now pdir conains the parent directory name
        cp -- "$f" "all_images/${pdir}_${c}.jpg"
        c=$((c+1))
    done
' findsh {} +
```

Sample directories with images:

```
$ ls dir*
dir1:
asj.jpg  assa.jpg

dir2:
kasj.jpg  kkl.jpg
```

After script execution:

```
$ ls all_images/
dir1_1.jpg  dir1_2.jpg  dir2_3.jpg  dir2_4.jpg
```

---

If you prefer the counter to be restarted upon source directory change, so that the result is `dir1_1.jpg  dir1_2.jpg  dir2_1.jpg  dir2_2.jpg`, then do a little adaptation in the for loop:

```
mkdir all_images
find -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
    for f in "$@"; do
        pdir=${f%/*}
        pdir=${pdir##*/} #Now pdir conains the parent directory name
        [ "$pdir" != "$oldpdir" ] && c=1
        cp -- "$f" "all_images/${pdir}_${c}.jpg"
        oldpdir=$pdir
        c=$((c+1))
    done
' findsh {} +
```